# download ftp folder using NppFtp in Notepad++

Tags: ftp, notepad++

I need to download site from ftp. I have Notepad++, so I think I can use NppFtp plugin. I connected to ftp, but I don't see how I can download or copy all site or just any folder. Only when I select one file and press right button I see "Download file" command. But how I can download folder?

**UPDATE**: okay, looked similar questions here and installed WinSCP, downloading site now.